# Android setTextViewCompoundDrawables for API 14

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm using `setTextViewCompoundDrawables` to set the compound drawables of a TextView inside a homescreen widget. However, I'm targeting API levels 14+, so I cannot use this method.

This is what I'm using at the moment:

```
cellRv.setTextViewCompoundDrawables(android.R.id.text1, 0, 0, 0, R.drawable.indicator);
```

I need to set the drawables programatically rather than from inside the XML layout I'm using, since I'm pulling data from a database to populate the widget.

Are there any alternate solutions to this?

Comment: That sentence: cellRv.setTextViewCompoundDrawables(...) is working for you on API 16+? I'm trying to add an XML shape to my TextViews inside an appwidget with no luck

Answer (score 0):

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
  cellRv.setTextViewCompoundDrawables(android.R.id.text1, 0, 0, 0, R.drawable.indicator);
}
```